# iPhone app for testing Push Notifications from Firebase

Tags: ios, node.js, firebase, push-notification

I am developing NodeJS code to sendPush Notifications using Google's Firebase.
Currently it works for my Browser (I can get PN in my browser) and now would want to test the same on some iPhone app.

Is there a way to install some iPhone app to test Push Notifications?

Is there some Developer iPhone app that can serve for this purpose?

Comment: There does not appear to be one, and I wouldn't imagine there is one based on the APNs token configuration required to send FCM messages to iOS.  If your FCM messages work on web, they will work on iOS once you properly configure your own app.

Comment: Yeah, the other part of the team is still developing app so I would not be able to test until they finish.. so was hoping to test with some 'sample app'. But thanks for confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

You can but it would be a static code with javascript,
It's called cordova, I've seen someone created an example of [it](https://github.com/christoga/firedova) at Android. You can export it to iOS & Windows Phone too.